# Need help to trace an abusive email hacker

Tags: ip-address, email, abuse

Can anyone help me how to trace back a pc/MAC address/IP Address/Location of an abuser. A mail was sent using one of our department's common email id by hacking into our email id and very abusive language was use. the mail was sent to very high officials and now our department's and company's reputation is at stake. It was a pure crime and we need to know who did it. the criminal used tor browser and we found X-Originating-IP: [176.10.107.180] in message header.

Can anyone help me in this regard.

if anymore information is needed about the mail please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to protect the users of the Tor network, it has been designed to not allow deanonymization by anyone. Not even by the exit node operator (who ever operates 176.10.107.180). If in fact this was possible, the Tor network would no longer be safe for activists, whistleblowers or anyone else in need of privacy. In order to deanonymize users, Governments could issue warrants, network operators could sell the information and since this information needed to be stored somewhere, the database could be hacked or seized. I'm very sorry to hear that this happened to you, it doesn't only hurt your company but also the reputation of the Tor network.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which country you're from but yeah, it sucks to end up in a situation like this.

If I were you, I'd approach whoever received this fake email and honestly explain to him the situation. You'll have to make it clear that this hate mail did not, in fact originate from anyone that work in the organization/company you are from. Also explain to them how Tor work.

BTW, you mentioned that your 'email id' was hacked by a third party, but you didn't specify what kind of email system you're using. Assuming you are using a commercial email system, that indicate either your password is weak or your computer that handles email was compromised by malware. If you still have access to the mailbox, either change password immediately or cancel it to prevent further exploits from happening. If you're using your organization's own email system, then your IT guy need to patch it up immediately.

If all else fails, you'll have no choice but cooperating with law enforcement. If you can identify the computer(s) that were compromised by hacker, make sure you prevent anyone from accessing them, you never know hacker might leave trails on them that may exonerate you and your company's name!